# Unable to pass command properly to remote computers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, citrix, xenapp

I've got a Powershell script that when copied to a local remote server and executed remotely using PSExec it correctly runs and does what I need it to do.  I was trying to adapt the same script to be able to be run remotely not relying on the script being copied and executed remotely with PSExec.  Its a command to have Citrix XenApp server join its Farm.

```
# Establish Variables
$ZoneName = "MyZone"
$OdbcUserName = "MyCitrixUserAcct"
$OdbcPassword = "MyPassword"
$LicenseServerName = "mylicenseserver.company.com"
$XAConfigConsoleExe = "C:\Progra~2\Citrix\XenApp\ServerConfig\XenAppConfigConsole.exe"
$Servers = Get-Content -path .\serverlist.txt
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
# Creating mf20.dsn File
if ((Test-Path \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn) -eq $true)
{
remove-item \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn
}
add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "[ODBC]"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "DRIVER=SQL Server"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "DATABASE=MyDB"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "APP=Citrix IMA"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "UID="
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "SERVER=dbserver.company.com,1433" 
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "Trusted_Connection=No"

# Setting setup arguments

[Array]$XAArguments = @()

$XAArguments += "/ExecutionMode:Join"
$XAArguments += "/ZoneName:$ZoneName"
$XAArguments += "/ImaWorkerMode:True"
$XAArguments += "/DsnFile:c:\temp\mf20.dsn"
$XAArguments += "/AuthenticationType:Sql"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcUserName:$OdbcUserName"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcPassword:$OdbcPassword"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerName:$LicenseServerName"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerPort:27000"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseModel:XA"
$XAArguments += "/CustomXMLServicePort:8080"

# running setup with arguments

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server {$XAConfigConsoleExe + $XAArguments}
}
```

I've tried a ton of different permutations and combinations (i.e. using -scriptblock, using pssessions) of things I've found through searches.  I know my command line is good because if I take the output of `write-host $XAConfigConsoleExe $XAArguments` and passed that to the Powershell console of the server it works.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  I didn't write the original script. I can't defend things like how the arguments are built, so if there is a better (more reliable way) then what I am doing here I am open to any ideas.

Here is what the original script that I can execute remotely with PSExec looks like:

```
# Establish Variables
$ZoneName = "MyZone"
$OdbcUserName = "MyCitrixUserAcct"
$OdbcPassword = "MyPassword"
$LicenseServerName = "mylicenseserver.company.com"
$XAConfigConsoleExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\XenApp\ServerConfig\XenAppConfigConsole.exe"

# Creating mf20.dsn File
if ((Test-Path C:\temp\mf20.dsn) -eq $true)
{
remove-item C:\temp\mf20.dsn
}
add-Content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "[ODBC]"
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "DRIVER=SQL Server"
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "DATABASE=MyDB"
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "APP=Citrix IMA"
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "UID="
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "SERVER=mydbserver.company.com,1433" 
add-content C:\temp\mf20.dsn "Trusted_Connection=No"

# Setting setup arguments
[Array]$XAArguments = @()

$XAArguments += "/ExecutionMode:Join"
$XAArguments += "/ZoneName:$ZoneName"
$XAArguments += "/ImaWorkerMode:True"
$XAArguments += "/DsnFile:C:\Temp\mf20.dsn"
$XAArguments += "/AuthenticationType:Sql"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcUserName:$OdbcUserName"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcPassword:$OdbcPassword"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerName:$LicenseServerName"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerPort:27000"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseModel:XA"
$XAArguments += "/CustomXMLServicePort:8080"

# running setup with arguments

& $XAConfigConsoleExe $XAArguments
```

Comment: Have you tried `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server $XAConfigConsoleExe -ArgumentList $XAArguments` ?

Comment: I had tried that, but it errors.  `Invoke-Command : Only PowerShell script files are allowed for FilePath parameter. Specify a file with .ps1 extension.
Parameter name: filePath`.  So that method doesn't work for calling something that isn't .PS1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've edited this answer to reflect the final version of the script I
>   went with.  I didn't change any logic or methods.  I merely cleaned up
>   some things and added more variables to make the script more flexible
>   for editing in the future.

Well it isn't the prettiest solution, but its the only reliable solution I could find that was completely self contained (outside of the input .txt file for the server list).  Nothing is copied from/to anywhere, everything is created dynamically.  Anyone with a sense of adventure is free to look it over and suggest better/cleaner ways to achieve my goal.

```
# Establish Variables
$ZoneName = Read-Host 'Zone Name?'
$OdbcUserName = "Citrixuser"
$OdbcPassword = Read-Host 'Password for Citrixuser?'
$LicenseServerName = "MyLicenseServer.company.com"
$DataBase= "DBName"
$DBServer= "MyDBServer.company.com"
$EdgeSightServer = "MyEdgeSightServer.company.com"

$XAConfigConsoleExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\XenApp\ServerConfig\XenAppConfigConsole.exe"
$Servers = Get-Content -path .\serverlist.txt

# Setting setup arguments

[Array]$XAArguments = @()

$XAArguments += "/ExecutionMode:Join"
$XAArguments += "/ZoneName:$ZoneName"
$XAArguments += "/ImaWorkerMode:True"
$XAArguments += "/DsnFile:C:\temp\mf20.dsn"
$XAArguments += "/AuthenticationType:Sql"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcUserName:$OdbcUserName"
$XAArguments += "/OdbcPassword:$OdbcPassword"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerName:$LicenseServerName"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseServerPort:27000"
$XAArguments += "/LicenseModel:XA"
$XAArguments += "/CustomXMLServicePort:8080"
$XAArguments += "/EdgeSightCompanyName:CompanyName"
$XAArguments += "/EdgeSightServerName:$EdgeSightServer"
$XAArguments += "/EdgeSightServerPort:80"

# Running against server list

ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
# Creating joinfarm.bat file on the remote server
if ((Test-Path \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat) -eq $true) {Remove-Item \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat}
Add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat "$([char]34)$XAConfigConsoleExe$([char]34) $XAArguments"
Add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat "shutdown.exe /r /f /t 10"
Add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat "del c:\temp\mf20.dsn /q"
Add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\joinfarm.bat "del c:\temp\joinfarm.bat /q"

# Creating mf20.dsn file on the remote server
if ((Test-Path \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn) -eq $true) {remove-item \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn}
add-Content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "[ODBC]"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "DRIVER=SQL Server"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "DATABASE=$DataBase"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "APP=Citrix IMA"
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "UID="
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "SERVER=$DBServer,1433" 
add-content \\$Server\c$\temp\mf20.dsn "Trusted_Connection=No"

# running setup with arguments
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {c:\temp\joinfarm.bat} -AsJob
}
```

What I'm doing is writing a batch file (I tried writing a PS1 file but it wasn't running any commands after the initial command when I ran the PS1 `-AsJob` even though it seemed to work if I didn't use `-AsJob`) to the remote server and executing the batch with `-AsJob` switch so that I can join multiple servers simultaneously. Without the `-AsJob` each server had to complete before the next was processed. The batch cleans itself, the dsn file, and reboots the server.

Comment: I'm adventurous... I'll have a look later.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy that would be appreciated.